# Are all Xperia Play Optimized games compatible with the Xperia Z/ZL's native DualShock 3 support?

Tags: applications, sony-xperia-z, sony-ericsson-xperia-play

The Xperia Play is a one-of-a-kind phone that supports a [physical keyboard](http://cdn.gottabemobile.com/wp-content/uploads/Xperia-Play-keyboard.jpg) for mobile gaming. Many games on the Play Store have been optimized to take advantage of these inputs.

Now, I've seen some videos showing that the Xperia Z & ZL have support for the DualShock 3 (the PS3 controller) without the need of rooting ([1](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oK9BsCPSMPg), [2](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0EeCmC7JyCk)). However, I was wondering: are games compatible with the Xperia Play keyboard automatically compatible for controller play on the Xperia Z/ZL? Or both types of optimization are completely different?

Comment: Are you trying to get Xperia Z/ZL games to work on Xperia Play? Is that what you're trying to say?

Comment: The other way around. I'm thinking on upgrading to an Xperia Z but was wondering if all those Xperia Play games I bought will work with the controller.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

User poo-tang provided an answer in the [xda forums](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showpost.php?p=40062080&postcount=5):

> Xperia Play games don't work this way so won't be interchangeable. These new games are HID (Native Android built in virtual controller/mouse) supported (only available on Android 3.1 and up) Xperia Play uses Sony framework only. The games are coded for one or another (sometimes both if developer has added support for both)